# Как правильно отправив POST запрос посредством ajax сменить csrf токен для использования его в следующем запросе?

Tags: ajax, yii2, csrf

Есть страница, которая в зависимости от выбора пользователя на ней, отправляет ajax-запросы и предлагает пользователю дальнейшие варианты действий.
При первоначальной загрузке страницы у неё формируется

```
<meta name="csrf-param" content="_csrf-frontend">
<meta name="csrf-token" content="..........G4Ds2pl0MtJX0lUJZs5y_cqZ-VuWRKKS1mczTbJa4G4w==">
```

Этот токен используется при запросах. Запросы отправляются методом POST и обрабатываются разными контроллерами, разными экшенами этих контроллеров. Страницу обновить после запроса мне нельзя - данные висят на стороне клиента и не сохраняются на сервере. Вот что не понятно и вот какая проблема:

1. По ходу того как пользователь выбирает варианты, отправляются запросы и получаются ответы, но некоторые запросы не обрабатываются и приходит ошибка. Т.е. не понятно почему одни запросы обрабатываются с помощью текущего токена, а другие нет.
2. Как я понимаю, токен должен быть "одноразовый", но как я написал в п.1. - одни запросы могут обработаться на одном и том же токене. Почему так?
3. Как правильно отправив POST запрос посредством ajax сменить csrf токен для использования его в следующем запросе и это ли нужно делать в ситуации, когда со страницы после её загрузки отправляются запросы? Вот [тут](https://qna.habr.com/q/392869) нашёл ответ

> Обменивайтесь токеном через куки. С сервера - обновляйте, а с клиента сам придет.

но сути не понял. Если он годный объясните, пожалуйста, что значит "обмениваться токеном через куки".

Comment: Если не критично, то эти токены можно отключить в контроллере во всех или в конкретных экшенах.

Comment: Это я знаю, но это не правильно. Надо все запросы ганять безопасно

Comment: csrf прописывается в коде страницы, поэтому он не обеспечивает безопасность. Просто некоторый инструмент, чтобы помешать отправить данные не со страницы. Хотя ничего не мешает забрать этот токен со страницы и отправить данные откуда угодно. Если страница закрыта авторизацией, то можно отключить. Либо генерить свой и писать в куки.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что он должен быть одноразовый? Т.е. второй post-запрос не должен проходить? Могу ли я вместе с ответом на первый запрос прислать новый токен для второго? Объяснить чуть подробнее, пожалуйста, про «писать в куки», саму логику, в какой момент его писать и тд. Авторизацией не защищено

Comment: Этот токен многоразовый. Например, если на странице три или больше форм? Все они подтверждаются одним токеном скорее всего. Если токен прописан в <meta, то он должен автоматом подставляться в заголовки запросов. Еще можно попробовать вкл/выкл передачи токена в куках.